# Can not setup visual studio code debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have downloaded VS code, but the debugger doesnt work. 
It says no configurations. I put a short video to show you what happens.
Thanks a lot.

[short video](https://gyazo.com/4754da917765c597aba0546110577566)

Comment: There is a bit of setup required. Have you followed the instructions on the Microsoft site - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with VS Code. The error is "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH", so that leads me to believe you either need to [download Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and/or add 'node' to your PATH. Run the following line from Command Prompt:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Nodejs;
```

It also wouldn't hurt to reboot afterward.